# c# null-coalescing operator (??) compiler code optimization

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am curious about the compiler efficiency in next case:

```
double total = list.Sum(x => x.Value) ?? 0;
```

Q: will compiler produce code that will execute the Sum function once or twice?

It could generate something like:

```
double total = list.Sum(x => x.Value) == null ? 0 : (double)list.Sum(x => x.Value);
```

or

```
double temp = list.Sum(x => x.Value);
total = temp == null ? 0 : (double)temp;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is pointless because even summing all nulls will result in 0.

```
var d = new int?[]{null,null};
d.Sum().Dump(); //0
```

...so `Enumerable.Sum()` will never yield the `null` value you're trying to guard against.

Comment: +1 - `This method returns zero if source contains no elements.` And
`The result doesnot include values that are null.` from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383052.aspx

Comment: @Habib the msdn documentation, which I read, is kind of unclear to me. What happens if the source contains only null? Is by source implied elements without null elements? They could just as easily say: the return result will never be null, that would be much clearer. The fact that method returns int? (for IEnumerable<int?>) led me thought wrongly that it CAN return null type.

Comment: @Goran: Agreed. Keeping the return type nullable seems silly.

Answer (score 4):

The code will execute the `Sum` once. That is the whole point of introducing a new operator into the language. You can verify this by introducing a condition with a side effect, and verifying that the side effect is applied only once:

```
int? x = 5;
int y = x++ ?? 100;
```

After executing this code, `x` is `6`, not `7`.

Comment: [Link to ideone](http://ideone.com/PIxPbo).

Answer (score 0):

The `??` operator is only applicable to the nullable types, and `double` is not a nullable type, so this code won't compile.
Same, the `.Sum()` extension method will never return `null` on this list, it will always return `0`.

Comment: I do not see any reason why the code would not compile...

Comment: In your case there are two problems with the code: (1) you are trying to co-alesce an `int` value for a `double`-typed variable (you should use `0.0` or `0d` if you want a double literal) and (2) you can't use the `??` operator if your argument is non-nullable (and `double` is non-nullable, compared to `double?`).

Comment: The argument is nullable if the list contains the Nullable<T> elements, so it will compile just fine.